# Handle concrete event from singleton object

Tags: c#, asynchronous, events, singleton, task

I'm trying implement event that will push to concrete subscriber, I have such as "singleton" this is shared object that share between many callers and callers that get the instance from ConcurrentDictionary it works as expected till I don't use the task. In the task, events push multicast for each subscriber that subscribe at this moment but I would like to push to particular subscriber that call method Execute at this moment, I play with RX .net but nothing had change when I make .Subscribe it looks like the same result seems need to include .ObserveOn but I don't have SynchronizationContext.Current inside Task.Run. Now I have a section in comment when I track it by Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId variable but I would like to handle it by Processor class.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var prName = "blah-blah-blah";
            var processor = ProcessorFactory.Get(prName);

            var taskArray = new Task[2];
            for (var i = 0; i < taskArray.Length; i++)
            {
                var idx = i;
                taskArray[i] = Task.Factory.StartNew(async () =>
                {
                    //var id = Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId;
                    EventHandler<string> handler = async (o, s) =>
                    {
                        //if (id == Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId)
                        //{
                        Console.WriteLine(
                            $"Task ID: {idx} - Processor thread is {Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId}");
                        //}
                    };
                    processor.OnStart += handler;
                    await processor.Execute<Data>();
                    await Task.Delay(2000);
                    //processor.OnStart -= handler;
                });
            }

            Task.WaitAll(taskArray);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
    public class Processor
    {
        public event EventHandler<string> OnStart;

        public async Task<T> Execute<T>() where T : new()
        {
            RaiseOnStart("Start");
            //some staff
            return new T();
        }
        private void RaiseOnStart(string eventArgs)
        {
            OnStart?.Invoke(this, eventArgs);
        }
    }

    public class ProcessorFactory
    {
        private static ConcurrentDictionary<string, Processor> _processors = new ConcurrentDictionary<string, Processor>();

        public static Processor Get(string str)
        {
            var processor = _processors.GetOrAdd(str, k =>
            {
                var clt = new Processor();
                return clt;
            });

            Console.WriteLine($"Processor count: {_processors.Count()}");

            return processor;
        }
    }

    public class Data
    {
    }
```

could you provide some solution or suggestion or explanation what am I do wrong.

Comment: pass handler to execute ... seriously, what are you expecting? `OnStart` is multicast delegate tasks has nothing to do with this ... `OnStart?.Invoke` will call all handlers currently registered

Comment: @Selvin I know that `OnStart?.Invoke`will call all handlers, do you mean impossible call particular handler at all?

Comment: Ok rhetorical question... And how you will choose caller handler inside execute?

Comment: @Selvin If only I knew about I didn't ask, but I think it should be because if you try get Environment.CurrentManagedThreadId inside Execute/RaiseOnStart this is same as a caller Id and maybe something have the synchronization between this points and we can track it. witch means I'm looking for thing that provide pipeline between these points. Also I can use sync primitives inside event add/remove methods but I don't need to lock it

Comment: Also I know what Stephen Cleary says : For this reason, I recommend the same approach that Jon Skeet ends up recommending at the end of Delegates and Events: "don't do that", i.e., don't use events in a multithreaded fashion. If an event exists on an object, then only one thread should be able to subscribe to or unsubscribe from that event, and it's the same thread that will raise the event.